# How to read check box data attribute value on page load

Tags: jquery

I have an array list of check boxes. When the user clicks on a specific checkbox I am reading respective checkbox `data-name` attribute values using the below code.

However some check boxes are checked on page load. I'm looking to know how I can read the `data-name` attribute value on page load for selected check boxes.

```
$(document).on("click", ":checkbox", function() {
  var fruitName = $(this).attr('data-name');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:checked` selector on load, then loop through them all:

```
$(function() {
  $(":checkbox:checked".each(doSomethingWithCheckbox); // on load
  $(document).on("click", ":checkbox", doSomethingWithCheckbox); // on click

  function doSomethingWithCheckbox() {
    var fruitName = $(this).data('name');
  }
});
```